# How to inject the username (not the Authentication)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, aop

In my spring boot application, in my rest controllers, I successfully inject an instance of `Authentication` to get the session's user information.

However, in all of those controllers, I currently call a helper method like this:

```
@GetMapping
public List<String> getData(Authentication auth) {
    String username = auth.getName().replaceFirst(".*?\\\\", ""); // to remove windows domain name
    // the rest of these methods only use variable `username`, never `auth`
}
```

How can I reduce this code duplication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a utility class as follows and then you can use it like this `UserUtility.getUsername()` wherever you need.

```
public class UserUtility {

    public static String getUsername(){
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! I called the class `CurrentUser` and the method `.getName()`, which makes my code super short and easy to read! Thanks!